# jq filtering - Cannot index array with string "Score"

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to find person name who has a subject and it score.
But i am getting index array.
This problem is different then other questions asked on Stackoverflow because it throws error for the parameter which is not in [] but in {}

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.result."*value*".Score.English) | {Name: .result."*value*".name, Subject: .result."*value*".Score.English} | @text' test.txt | sed 's/^{\|}$//g; s/,/\n/'
```

INPUT JSON FILE

```
[{
    "host": "testserver",
    "hostclass": "Unknown",
    "result": {
        "*value*": [
            {
                "sessionId": "000001",
                "name": "ABC",
                "Age": "21",
                "Score": {
                    "English": "A+",
                    "Mathematics": "B-",
                    "String Theory": "C+"
                }
            },
            {
                "sessionId": "000001",
                "name": "CDE",
                "Age": "21",
                "Score": {
                    "English": "A-",
                    "German": "B-",
                    "French": "C+"
                }
            },
            {
                "sessionId": "000001",
                "name": "EFG",
                "Age": "21",
                "Score": {
                }
            },
            {
                "sessionId": "000001",
                "name": "XYZ",
                "Age": "21"
            }]
   }
}]
```

OUTPUT :

```
Name: ABC
Subject : A+
Name: CDE
Subject : A-
```

ERROR :

```
jq: error (at test.txt:39): Cannot index array with string "Score"
```

how can i fix this error?

Comment: `*value*` is an array. So `.result."*value*".Score` will always fail. You seem to want the `Score` property of the objects contained within that array... `.result."*value*"[].Score`. This would fix the error, but wouldn't make it correct however.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to expand arrays to access elements in them,
2. You don't need sed at all.

```
$ jq -r '.[].result."*value*"[] | select(.Score.English) | "Name: \(.name)", "Subject: \(.Score.English)"' file
Name: ABC
Subject: A+
Name: CDE
Subject: A-
```

Answer (score 0):

**EFG** **Score** is of length 0 that probably doesn't help :

```
"sessionId": "000001",
"name": "EFG",
"Age": "21",
"Score": {}
```

So it chokes when trying to evaluate :

```
Subject: .result."*value*".Score.English
```